# Internet Explorer is not opening from selenium 2.48 for Java

Tags: java, selenium

I am using selenium 2.48, windows 8.1, 64(Bit). IEDriverServer.exe 2.48, JDK 1.7. Connection is good. But I am not able to open internet explorer 11 from selenium code.

It's throwing below error:

> Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
>   2.48.0.0
>   Listening on port 
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
>
> Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:47177 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection timed out: connect
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:151)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:143)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:89)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
>       ... 9 more

Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: I just switched to selenium 2.53.1 and IEDriverServer 2.53.1.0. It worked.

Comment: Hi, if the problem is solved, please put your answer and mark as accepted, it is a good for the future for the similar problems, thank you :)

Comment: Done. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I just switched to selenium 2.53.1 and IEDriverServer 2.53.1.0. It worked.